# Como faço para desativar uma função quando e API antiga do android

Tags: android, api

Tenho a função `View.OnScrollChangeListener` que foi implantada apenas na API 23. 
Nas API anteriores exemplo a do KitKat API 19. Essa função não funciona. 
Como eu faço no meu código `oncreate` quando chamar a função ele verificar API para executar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve verificar qual a API usada pelo usuário da aplicação

Exemplo:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // faz algo do Lollipop em diante
} else{
    // faz algo do Lollipop para trás
}
```